# Fix the upstream dependency conflict, react-share with React 18, Deployment failed in Netlify

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, react-share

Unable to install react-share on React 18 project and failed deployment on Netlify

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0 || ^17" from react-share@4.4.0
      
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps react-share
```

Answer (score 0):

First, utilize the advised command `npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps react-share`

then, in your app root directory create a `.npmrc` file

lastly add to the file `legacy-peer-deps=true`

and you're ready to deploy.

The **--legacy-peer-deps** flag was introduced with v7 as a way to bypass peerDependency auto-installation; it tells NPM to ignore peer deps and proceed with the installation anyway.

**npmrc** is the configuration file that npm allows to be used globally or user level or project level to optimize your npm environment. npmrc can be configured in four different locations. Globally. Per user. Per project.

Answer (score 0):

Check the peer dependencies of `react-share@4.4.0`:

```
$ npm view react-share@4.4.0 peerDependencies
{ react: '^16.3.0 || ^17' }
```

This means [`react-share`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share) package version 4.4.0 only works with `react` with version: `'^16.3.0 || ^17'`. But the `react` installed in your project is 18.x.x version, it's incompatible with version specified in `peerDependency` field. That's why you got the warning when trying to install it.

Two solutions:

- [4.4.1 release](https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/releases/tag/v4.4.1) support React 18 in `peerDependencies`.

We can verify it via npm command

```
$ npm view react-share@4.4.1 peerDependencies
{ react: '^16.3.0 || ^17 || ^18' }
```

Or, this [commit](https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/commit/75a6b6baa0d71a4f676d63ff8e23a40f62d218dd#diff-7ae45ad102eab3b6d7e7896acd08c427a9b25b346470d7bc6507b6481575d519R93)

- Downgrading `react` package to those two versions: `'^16.3.0 || ^17'`